# Finding date time difference in minutes in KDB

Tags: kdb

How do you find the time difference in minutes between 2 datetimes in KDB?

Example:

```
(2015.08.26+02:00)-(2015.08.25+00:00)
```

Should give 1560 minutes or 26 hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`` q)`minute$(2015.08.26+02:00)-(2015.08.25+00:00)
26:00
q)`int$`minute$(2015.08.26+02:00)-(2015.08.25+00:00)
1560i ``

I recommend following the tutorials available online as it will give you a firmer basis for understanding kdb. Once you know the datatypes available in kdb and how they are stored, a number of operations with time become much simpler. In this case I am casting using the dollar symbol, with the type on the left and my data on the right.